# Combine many MStest *.trx files into one

Tags: mstest, trx

We are using Microsoft agents & controllers to execute many CodedUI tests in parallel across many Virtual Machines.  This produces many .trx results files.  Is there anyway to merge all of our TRX files back into one trx file?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this: https://github.com/rndsolutions/trx-merger ? I haven't used it, but it looks promising.

Comment: Thanks!  that seems to work for me :)

Comment: Did not work for me. The merge succeeded but the merged file could not be openened successfully in VS2017 Test Result window.